# Playing Minecraft in Ubuntu - Black lines

Tags: java, minecraft

[image]Help me please. Complete novice on Ubuntu ( on day 2 ) and trying to get this working for son for his christmas present ( one of many!!! )

I have Ubuntu 13.04 installed, have followed the instructions to download Java and i am launching by opening with Oracle Java 7 runtime ( manually by selecting open with )

When the screen comes up to play it looks like black slashes and lines / flashing triangles through, glitchy?? ( not very technical i know!! )

The same funky lines / triangles have shown up sometimes when just running Ubuntu, but not to the extent that it does on Minecraft.

What am i doing wrong?

I have recently purchased the Asus A85XM-A mother board and installed this myself with a total of 8GB memory too. I am running Ubuntu through a 64GB USB stick.

This is what was recommended to me to get and do by the guys at Maplin.

HEEELLLLPPPP! PLEASE :)

Thanks

Kerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Minecraft installer. Run following code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
```

Once installed simply run the app, enter (or register) your Minecraft details and you’re all set

Source: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/minecraft-installer-for-ubuntu

OR

Step 1 - Files/Programs
Go to the Ubuntu Software Center and install OpenJDK Java 6...
Get minecraft.jar from http://www.minecraft.net/download/minecraft.jar and place in you home directory.
Get minecraft.svg from the attachments at the bottom of this post and put it in the same place.

Step 2 - Terminal
Open the terminal and type: sudo bash
Enter your password (not the root one)
Then type: ls
Check if the files you added are there.
If they are type: chmod a+x minecraft.jar
This will make it run-able
Close the terminal

Step 3 - Open with
Go to the minecraft.jar file and right-click on it
Select preferences and set it to open with OpenJDK Java 6...

Step 4 - Launcher
Add a launcher on the desktop (right-click)
Click on the image and locate minecraft.svg
Name it Minecraft
Set the location as the minecraft.jar file

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1812767

Comment: Tried this and its gone to a completely black screen after added details. As im getting these strange lines on Ubuntu when im in other programmes and files could it be the Ubuntu download itself?

Comment: Which one of the two methods did you try?

Comment: Both, first didnt do anything different, 2nd changed and worked step by step until logged on then minecraft screen went black

Comment: can i post a picture of what im seeing on here? if so how would i do it lol.

Comment: Edit your question and click on the little img icon. I'm gonna try and follow the second tutorial on a virtual machine

Comment: Grrrr says i don't have enough reputation points to post a picture

Comment: I upvoted your question, do you have enough reputation now?

Comment: On 6 need 10 to post pics

Comment: picture at top shows lines, these were popping up everywhere. Also see faded versions of this while just on Ubuntu normally

Comment: Never played Minecraft before but I don't see anything wrong with it?

Comment: Its the black lines at the top right of the screen. They are flickering all over the screen.